# Using a public PRNG and uniform distribution (C++17)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, random, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to implement a PRNG I found online yet I am having compile time issues (seen below):

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\xutility(4010): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'result_type'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\xutility(4012): error C2065: '_Ty1': undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\xutility(4012): error C2065: '_Ty1': undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\xutility(4012): error C2923: 'std::conditional_t': '_Ty1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty2'
```

This is my code:

```
std::random_device rd;
small_prng engine;
std::uniform_int_distribution< int > ud( 0, 50 );

for ( auto i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
    printf( "%i\n", ud( engine ) );
}
```

And this is the code I got online...

```
class small_prng {
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint32_t c;
    uint32_t d;

    static inline uint32_t rot( uint32_t x, uint32_t k ) noexcept {
        return ( ( ( x ) << ( k ) ) | ( ( x ) >> ( 32 - ( k ) ) ) );
    }
public:
    using value_type = uint32_t;

    explicit small_prng( uint32_t seed = 0xdeadbeef ) noexcept {
        a = 0xf1ea5eed;
        b = c = d = seed;
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < 20; ++i )
            ( *this )( );
    }

    inline uint32_t operator()( ) noexcept {
        uint32_t e = a - rot( b, 27 );
        a = b ^ rot( c, 17 );
        b = c + d;
        c = d + e;
        d = e + a;
        return d;
    }
};
```

Is there any reason this isn't working? How come? Compiling using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Better use [`<random>` standard header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: Where is the class definition?

Comment: apologies @MatteoItalia added it now.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'd rather not... the entire reason I'm doing this is for performance.

Comment: Have you benchmarked?  [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) runs very quickly

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This is 2.5-3 times faster. http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bob-jenkins-small-prng-passes-practrand.html

Comment: And you really need such a speed, even if getting a much worse PRNG ?

Comment: If you want performance, download Intel MKL. They have a very fast implementation of Mersenne Twister (SFMT19937). They also have a very fast implementation of transformation from uniform to Gaussian.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it's not worse... mersenne twister begins failing pracrand tests at 512GB of input whereas bob jenkin's small prng (in the post above) passes up to 1TB (and maybe more... untested iirc)

Comment: I'll check it out but I really wanted to test out this specific random number generator after all the amazing things I've heard about it @Fabio. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements for a random engine are outlined at [rand.req.eng]; [you can find here a summary of them](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomNumberEngine); in particular you are missing (highlighted through the code with a `MISSING` comment):

```
class small_prng {
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint32_t c;
    uint32_t d;

    static inline uint32_t rot( uint32_t x, uint32_t k ) noexcept {
        return ( ( ( x ) << ( k ) ) | ( ( x ) >> ( 32 - ( k ) ) ) );
    }
public:
    // MISSING: the result type must indeed be called `result_type`
    using result_type = uint32_t;

    // MISSING: you must provide min and max, with the
    // minimum/maximum value your RNG can return
    result_type min() const noexcept { return 0; }
    result_type max() const noexcept { return 0xffffffff; }

    explicit small_prng( result_type seed = 0xdeadbeef ) noexcept {
        a = 0xf1ea5eed;
        b = c = d = seed;
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < 20; ++i )
            ( *this )( );
    }

    // MISSING: constructor from a SeedSequence (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SeedSequence)
    template<typename S>
    explicit small_prng(S &seq) {
        uint32_t nseed[1];
        seq.generate(nseed, nseed+1);
        seed(nseed[0]);
    }

    // MISSING: seed() overloads
    void seed() { *this = small_prng(); }
    void seed(result_type seed) { *this = small_prng(seed); }
    template<typename S> void seed(S &seq) { *this = small_prng(seq); }

    inline result_type operator()( ) noexcept {
        uint32_t e = a - rot( b, 27 );
        a = b ^ rot( c, 17 );
        b = c + d;
        c = d + e;
        d = e + a;
        return d;
    }

    // MISSING: discard n extractions
    void discard(unsigned long long z) {
        // does this engine implement more efficient jump-ahead?
        while(z--) (*this)();
    }

    // MISSING: dump generator state operator
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const small_prng &r) {
        return os<<r.a<<" "<<r.b<<" "<<r.c<<" "<<r.d<<" ";
    }

    // MISSING: read from generator state dump operator
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, small_prng &r) {
        return is>>r.a>>r.b>>r.c>>r.d;
    }
};
```

Comment: is the sequence constructor call correct? [This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SeedSequence) suggests the arguments should denote a range to write into.